# A library for nodejs connection with backend

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, backend

i am creating a node application which will use a another node backend, like a CLI program, **which Node.js library or framework will i use for this situation?** the axios not is working in my tests.

thanks for reading.

Comment: Would you please explain what do you mean by "another node backend, like a CLI program"?

Comment: I have a Node.js backend with routes, database connection,etc. i am creating a node.js CLI program which will use this node backend, and i dont know any node library or framework to make this, and axios is not working in my tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do http requests from within node.js there are several options: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch, axios is also available. Could you please share some errors you get?

I always use node-fetch because I am most familiar with the fetch API, previously I used this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest

As seen in your answer you are using /users as url, please use the full url. Also catch any unexpected errors.

So `axios.get('http://domain/users')`

Comment: @EdersonFerreira I changed the answer, please take a look

Comment: Now have no error in axios, a changed from GET, to PUT, but my script never ends and nothing was changed in database, i will put my code in a answer, thanks for the attention.

Answer (score -1):

I SOLVED THE PROBLEM!

the problem was in the axios connection, now its:

```
async function execQuery(apps){
    data = ({
        name: "ederson",
        apps: "neofetch"
    })

    const response = await axios.put('http://localhost:3333/users', data
    ).then(console.log(apps))
}
```

**Thanks for help me, Laurent Dhont and Ahmed Hammad!**